# I have a problem with discord.js v12 when trying to run the bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

im running a discord.js v12 bot and when i try to run it
this error pops up

```
      client.user.setActivity(newActivity);
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setActivity')
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Alexu\Desktop\cookie checker\events\ready.js:19:19)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:568:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:510:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

This means the client is not ready at the time. Put this in the `ready` event

```js
client.once("ready", () => {
  client.user.setActivity(newActivity)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems correct. That the value is null maybe means that no user was found. Maybe something goes wrong with login. If the rest of the functions also don't work, then I would advise checking if the credentials are correct.